# Isolated mosfet switching circuit

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator, isolation

I have designed the circuit below for a isolated digital output from a mcu. The switching speed is slow -- only 100ms or so. I would like to be able to switch between 3 and 24Vdc at about 1mA to 500mA. Is this the correct way to build a circuit like this? 
[image]

[APV2111VY](http://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/relay/photomos/catalog/semi_eng_apv.pdf)

Comment: Welcome. For future reference it would be a nice gesture to provide links to the parts (in this case, the PV coupler, and the two MOSFETs and the TVS). You'll get better results.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany for now I don't have enough reputation points to post more links!

Answer (score 2):

It looks good to me. Make sure that your voltage on PA6 is enough to reliably operate the 2N7002- you might want to use a lower Vgs MOSFET if your input voltage could be low.

Of course you could use an N-channel MOSFET for the output instead, but it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Does it not need a pull-down to switch Q8 on reasonably quickly?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes-- not shown in the OP's schematic is a circuit inside the photovoltaic coupler that turns it off in about 100usec.

Comment: 2N7002 is N-channel, as I am sure you well know. Did you mean to type "you could use a P-channel MOSFET instead?"

Comment: @mkeith I was referring to the output transistor, which is a small P-channel transistor. Will edit to make it clear, thanks.

Comment: I am using a P-channel because I use it in other places on this board -- to avoid another BOM line. I am switching the 2N7002 with 3.3V... I see that I should select a different one for that because this one is for 5V logic levels.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct way to build a circuit like this?

The correct way in my book is to use an Omron G3VM SSR but everyone will have their favourite ways: -

[image]

They cost about $2, can handle 60V AC or DC and can switch loads up to 500 mA. They need 3mA to activate and can switch on and off in under 2ms. On resistance typically about 1 ohm and output capacitance a surprisingly low 30pF.

Data sheet [here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/77352.pdf)

Comment: this looks like a nice part. thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem on the output pin. Presumably the load will be connected between positive supply and D0_I.

1. Initially Q1 is off so no current is flowing.
2. When the opto-isolator turns on Q8's gate will get charged turning on Q8. The voltage on D0_I will fall to zero.
3. This will drop the voltage that's turning on Q8 in the first place so Q8 will start to turn off.

The opto-isolator diodes should have a separate connection to the external load's positive supply.

As @ThePhoton has said, to turn Q8 off the gate will need a pull-down resistor. There is none shown on your schematic.

Comment: the APV2111VY has a photovoltiac output so the voltage comes from there.

Comment: @WRT54GL: Ah, right. I missed that when I scanned the data sheet. I've never come across these before. When the LED turns on will the

Comment: Ah, thank you @WRT54GL! I've always used opto-isolators of the photo-transistor type. So, will the gate be driven positive with respect to the top terminal of the MosFET. How exactly does turn off work?

Comment: quoting sphero from his comment above: Yes-- not shown in the OP's schematic is a circuit inside the photovoltaic coupler that turns it off in about 100usec.

Comment: But does the turn-off discharge the gate? i.e., is turn-off a short-circuit? The data-sheets I looked at don't give much away. Usually, to minimise power dissipation in the MosFET we turn it hard on and hard off as quickly as possible.